# Запятые вокруг "как всегда" или лучше тире?

Tags: запятые

Запятые вокруг "как всегда" или лучше тире? 
В программе вечера как всегда - танцы до упаду и веселые конкурсы.
Запятые или тире нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил так:
***В программе вечера, как всегда, — танцы до упаду и веселые конкурсы.***

Логика такая. "Как всегда" не обособляется, если оно входит в состав сказуемого именной частью: *Дальше все было как всегда* или тесно связано  с ним по смыслу.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_313

Представить "как всегда" частью сказуемого не получается, даже если считать, что сказуемое — опущенный глагол-связка (это уже очень большая натяжка, грамматика здесь другая). Но тогда в прошедшем или будущем времени получается "в программе вечера было/будет как всегда" — не хватает подлежащего для признания "было как всегда" сказуемым.

Поэтому ничего другого не остается, кроме как признать "как всегда" вводной конструкцией — это, кстати, почти всегда так. 
Таким образом, нужно обособление. Обособление подобных вводных конструкций вполне обеспечивается запятыми, парные тире в этом случае вещь совершенно избыточная. Плюс ко всему одно тире в тексте уже есть, и оно поставлено по другим мотивам. 
Отсюда и запятые вокруг вводного.

На самом деле я разжевал вполне очевидную вещь, но вы так вопрос поставили.

Answer (score 0):

"Как всегда" обособляется запятыми, а вот тире, по-моему, лишнее, но о его использовании лучше было бы судить по более объёмному приведённому фрагменту текста.